# Confused by "undefined reference" linker error, and inability to find culprit object file

Tags: c, linker, undefined

I have a large, mixed (C, C++) workspace with a complex make file layout. I'm porting in a new library, and working through compilation issues. I have a GNU linker error (in what I am pretty sure is entirely sourced from C code in this instance) of the form:

path/to/object_file.o: In function `function_name':
(.text+0x0x11e4a0): undefined reference to `missing_function'

Now, it is my expectation that if I execute the "strings" command on object_file.o, I should see reference to both function_name and missing_function. I find neither. If I peruse the output of "strings," I do see other symbols that I recognize, so it is not mangling everything.

Is it possible that the linker error message is inaccurate?

I did find the command which builds object_file.o. It is another linker of a bunch of .a files. I executed "strings" on each of them, and did not find function_name in any of them.

So, I am trying to find the build process steps that lead up to this error, as I am not sure that function_name is relevant in this linking step. Any tips on how to do this are appreciated.

Comment: No, strings would only show you that if you had compiled the binary with debugging symbols. Use `readelf -s` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I have never heard of readelf before. I do see missing_function, but not function_name using readelf -s object_file.o | grep function_name

Comment: Order of the libraries in the command line when linking may be important, this is sometimes an issue.

Comment: @iharob But how is the linker supposed to know the name of `missing_function` if it is not contained in the binary? Btw. current GNU strings is elf-aware and prettyprints many parts

Comment: Okay, so for me the solution seems to be to use readelf -s (or -a) missing_function on the .o and .a files. Although I can't find function_name in these files, at least I can find missing_function, and ultimately the command that pulls this in. (Sorry, I'm not sure how to mark iharob's message as the solution to my problem.)